# Well-defined set in naive set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am wondering what is a *well-defined* set in the context of Naive set theory (since Wikipedia says that Naive set theory is often sufficient to do math).

Wikipedia says that “in Naive set theory, a **set** is described as a *well-defined* collection of objects.” Does *well-defined* here mean that given a collection of objects, it is a **set** if an element (anything) is either in it or not (no ambiguity)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In Mathematics, there are many ways one might inadvertently try and define some object that, on the surface, *seems* to make sense but which, after careful inspection, ends up being troublesome. This can happen quite easily, for example, when one is working with functions if you're not careful. For instance, suppose for each integer $n \geq 2$ I try and define the "function" $f: \mathbb{Z_{\geq2}} \to \mathbb{Z}$ by $f(n) = p$ if $p$ is a prime number which divides $n$.

We might say, okay, this definition for $f$ *seems* to make sense. For instance, I notice that $2$ is the only prime number dividing $2$, so by this definition, we will have $f(2) = 2$. Same thing with $f(3)$. Since $3$ is the only prime number dividing $3$, we conclude $f(3) = 3$. Okay, great! We might conclude that this function $f$ is good to go! But wait a minute...what would something like $f(12)$ be?? We might say that the prime number $2$ divides $12$, so we could claim $f(12) = 2$. But, the prime $3$ also divides $12$, so maybe $f(12) = 3$. So which is it? Is $f(12)$ two, or is it three, or is it something else? Since $f(12)$ could conceivably take on multiple values, instead of just 1 value, based on my definition, it turns out I haven't properly defined the function $f$ after all! We would say that the "function" $f$ which I outlined above is not well-defined (it is **ill-defined**). Thus, if I try to define the "set" $A = \{ f(n): n > 2\}$, we're going to run into some issues that make our brain hurt (spoiler alert: $A$ is not actually a set since many of the values $f(n)$ are themselves not well-defined).

Generally speaking, mathematicians will say some object is not *well-defined* if the definition for said object leaves room for ambiguity on what the object is supposed to be. That is, a Mathematician $A$ and a Mathematician $B$ could conceivably read the same definition and come up with mutually incompatible (but valid) interpretations of what they just read. In the example above, Mathematician $A$ could claim $f(12) = 2$ (and their interpretation wouldn't violate the definition they read), but mathematician $B$ could say $f(12) = 3$, and their interpretation also wouldn't violate the definition...yet their interpretations of what $f(12)$ should be are definitely incompatible since $2$ is not the same as $3$.

Comment: Thank you! So does a *well-defined* collection means that there is no ambiguity in what elements the collection has?

Comment: That is correct! In the example with the $A$, there's ambiguity on whether or not the number $2$ is an element of $A$ depending on the stance one has for the value of $f(12)$. The same is true for the number $3$ - is it an element of $A$? Nobody knows! Thus, we can't really say $A$ is a set.

Comment: Thank you! @Michael

Comment: " I notice that 2 is the only prime number which divides itself" - not true , you mean "$2$ is the only prime dividing $2$" , and we can replace $2$ by any other prime.

Comment: @Peter good catch - I've amended my answer accordingly.